# Mathematical representation of a pinescript code

Tags: pine-script

I have found a pine script called "momentum strategy" which works well for me. However my trading platform supports a different script. So I need to understand the mathematics behind this code (I mean how the value is calculated) so that I would be able to develop something similar in my trading software. Can anyone please help me. The code is as follows.

The last two lines are understandable. But the rest is not.

```
momentum(seria, length) =>
    mom = seria - seria[length]
    mom

mom0 = momentum(price, length)
mom1 = momentum( mom0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` in  `pine-script` is called [History Reference Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator). You can access to variable values for the previous bars using this operator. `close[1]` returns the close price of one bar ago.

```
momentum(seria, length) =>
    mom = seria - seria[length]
    mom
```

Here, `seria` is your input. `seria - seria[length]` will return the difference between current value of `seria` and its value for the "length" bars ago. Then in the next line that only has `mom`, the function returns the value of `mom`.